# get file size with ifstream::seekg and tellg

Tags: c++, c

I have the following block to test the behaviours of the seekg and tellg when I try to get a file size:

```
    int size = 0;
    ifstream in(fileName.c_str(), ifstream::in | ifstream::binary);
    if(in)
    {
        in.seekg(0,ifstream::end);
        size = in.tellg();
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "********** size stream1*** =" << size << endl;
        in.seekg(0,ios::end);
        size = in.tellg();
        cout << "********** size stream2*** =" << size << endl;
        in.seekg(0,ios::end);
        size = in.tellg();
        cout << "********** size stream3*** =" << size << endl;
        in.seekg(100,ios::end);
        size = in.tellg();
        cout << "********** size stream4*** =" << size << endl;
        in.seekg(0,ios::beg);
        size = in.tellg();
        cout << "********** size stream5*** =" << size << endl;
        in.seekg(100);
        in.seekg(0, ios::end);
        size = in.tellg();
        cout << "********** size stream6*** =" << size << endl;
        in.seekg(100);
        in.seekg(0, ios::cur);
        size = in.tellg();
        cout << "********** size stream7*** =" << size << endl;
        in.seekg(-100,ios::end);
        size = in.tellg();
        cout << "********** size stream8*** =" << size << endl;
        in.seekg(ios::beg,ios::end);
        size = in.tellg();
        cout << "********** size stream9*** =" << size << endl;
        in.seekg(ios::beg);
        in.seekg(ios::end);
        size = in.tellg();
        cout << "********** size stream10*** =" << size << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Its results are followed:

```
********** size stream1*** =1846
********** size stream2*** =1846
********** size stream3*** =1846
********** size stream4*** =1946
********** size stream5*** =0
********** size stream6*** =1846
********** size stream7*** =100
********** size stream8*** =1746
********** size stream9*** =1846
********** size stream10*** =2
```

My questions are the following:

1. does the **tellg** will return the bytes the last **seekg** found?
2. Why the **stream5** result is 0? its previous position is at the end of the file.
3. **seekg** will always start at beginning of the file as shown in **stream5**?
4. **seekg** cannot go backward as shown in **stream5**?
5. what's the first parameter of seekg really mean? It says it is the offset of the second parameter. It seems it goes beyond the position pointed by the second parameter if it is a positive value, as showing in **stream4**.
6. If I want to know the size after the first 100 bytes, I have to use the -100 as shown in **stream8**?
7. why **stream10** is 2?
8. **seekp** and **tellp** in ofstream have the properties as **seekg** and **tellg** here?

Comment: tellg returns the current position of the file. **read the man pages.** by the way, you only have one stream.

Comment: You call in.seekg(0,ios::beg); before stream5. Why should it be anything other than 0?

Comment: Also for 6, why not simply get full size and substract 100? If the file is below 100 bytes you could be setting the position below beginning of the stream. I tested this out and for a smaller file the return size is -1 which I believe is failbit error set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here we go:

1. No. `tellg()` will yield the position object useful to get back to the position you are at. The type returned is a `std::streampos` which is `std::fpos<std::mbstate_t>`. However, an `std::fpos<std::mbstate_t>` converts to a `std::streamoff` which is an integer. Essentially, a `std::streampos` converts to the number of characters from the first position to the current position.
2. Seeking to `0` characters relative to `std::ios_base::beg` clearly sets the position to the start of the file. Did you mean to use `std::ios_base::cur`?
3. No. `seekg()` will be relative to the start, current position, or the end depending on the *whence* parameter being `std::ios_base::beg`, `std::ios_base::cur`, or `std::ios_base::end`.
4. No. You can go backward using a negative offset.
5. See 3.: the first parameter is the offset being moved relative to the location specified by the *whence* parameter.
6. No. If you know how many characters are in the file, you subtract 100 from that number.
7. You used absolute positioning using the *whence* values as position. The `std::ios_base::seekdir` type is an enumeration and `std::ios_base::end` probably has the value `2`.
8. Pretty much.